# find a minimum : $f(x) = x^{(2/3)}$

Tags: calculus

$$ f(x)= x^{(2/3)} $$

the derivative is:

$$ f'(x) = \frac{2}{3x^{(1/3)}} $$

I tried:

$$ f'(x) = \frac{2}{3x^{(1/3)}} = 0 $$
there is no solution.

In the exam solutions, $x=0$ is a local and global minimum. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A local (and therefore also a global) minimum must be one of

1. A point where the derivative is zero,
2. A point where the function isn't differentiable, or
3. A point on the boundary of the domain.

Your calculation investigates only the first of these possibilities.

Comment: the function isn't differentiable in x=0. this is the reason to check x=0?

Comment: @Silas2033: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that $f(x)>0$ when $x > 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ when $x = 0$.